# Perverse sheaves (or D-modules) on vector spaces, constructible with respect to a hyperplane arrangement

Tags: algebraic-topology, d-modules

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex vector space and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a finite collection of hyperplanes in $V$. Stratify $V$ by the intersections of elements of $\mathcal{A}$, and consider the category of perverse sheaves on $V$ (or, if you prefer, regular holonomic D-modules) that are constructible with respect to this stratification. I am interested in learning how to explicitly identify this category with a certain category of representations of a quiver. I have in mind the following example, having already understood the stratification of the one dimensional vector space $\mathbb{C}$ arising from one hyperplane $\{ 0 \}$: let $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ with hyperplanes
$$x=0, \quad y=0, \quad x+y=0.$$ I know the definitions of vanishing and nearby cycles already, and I'd appreciate expert help doing these explicit calculations!

Comment: It really is spelled "constructible".

Comment: Also, I know that "representations of a quiver" is somehow too much to hope for---the big stratum in my example has a somewhat complicated fundamental group (seems to be the pure braid group on three strands). The point is that I'd like a concrete description via gluing.

Comment: Have a look at this [Kapranov's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5800.pdf).

Comment: @user10000100_u Excellent! Thanks very much. If you like, you can convert you comment into an answer that I'll happily accept (the paper is exactly an answer to my question).

Comment: Done ;-) Nothing new in it

Comment: Actually, I didn't see from mobile, but I already posted this very same answer, which was converted automatically to a comment. Apparently, folks here won't let you decide if you like an answer or not, they'll decide for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at this Kapranov's and Schechtman's paper called "Perverse sheaves over real hyperplane arrangements", that you can find on arxiv here :

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5800.pdf

It may interest you.

Comment: A small quibble (again, thanks for pointing out the existence of the paper!): that paper has two authors, and you should refer to them both on this page.

Comment: Absolutely, done.